# Using cv.ComputeCorrespondEpilines() in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, multiple-matches

I have two images of the same object taken at different views. My objective is to find the matching keypoints from the two images. Then I want to select  keypoints from one image and draw the corresponding epipolar lines in the other image. I am using **Python** and **OpenCV** for my experiments. I have been able to find the *keypoints* and the *mathpoints* from the two images. I have been able to draw the point correspondence.

But I am not being able to find the function '`ComputeCorrespondEpilines()`' in **python cv2 module**. Since I am using **numpy** arrays I cannot use cv module for using this function. It seems that there is no `ComputeCorrespondEpilines()` function in cv2.

Using numpy with the `cv.ComputeCorrespondEpilines()` gives this error:

```
  cv.ComputeCorrespondEpilines(mp_array,1, cv.fromarray(F1),cv.fromarray(liness))
TypeError: object does not have array interface
```

(`mp_array` is a numpy array of tuples.)

I converted the `mp_array` to list of tuple s . But the same error occurred.

Here is my code:

```
    import cv
import cv2
import sys
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

img1_path = sys.argv[1]
img2_path = sys.argv[2]
img1_ = cv2.imread(img1_path, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
img2_ = cv2.imread(img2_path, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("BRIEF")
matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create("BruteForce-Hamming")

detect keypoints
kp1 = detector.detect(img1)
kp2 = detector.detect(img2)

print '#keypoints in image1: %d, image2: %d' % (len(kp1), len(kp2))

# descriptors
k1, d1 = descriptor.compute(img1, kp1)
k2, d2 = descriptor.compute(img2, kp2)

print '#descriptors in image1: %d, image2: %d' % (len(d1), len(d2))

# match the keypoints
matches = matcher.match(d1, d2)
dist = [m.distance for m in matches]

print 'distance: min: %.3f' % min(dist)
print 'distance: mean: %.3f' % (sum(dist) / len(dist))
print 'distance: max: %.3f' % max(dist)

# threshold: half the mean
thres_dist = (sum(dist) / len(dist)) * 0.5

# keep only the reasonable matches
sel_matches = [m for m in matches if m.distance < thres_dist]

print '#selected matches:', len(sel_matches)
points1=[];#1
points2=[];#1

# #####################################
# visualization
h1, w1 = img1_.shape[:2]
h2, w2 = img2_.shape[:2]
view = sp.zeros((max(h1, h2), w1 + w2, 3), sp.uint8)
view[:h1, :w1, 0] = img1_
view[:h2, w1:, 0] = img2_
view[:, :, 1] = view[:, :, 0]
view[:, :, 2] = view[:, :, 0]

for m in sel_matches:
   # draw the keypoints
   # print m.queryIdx, m.trainIdx, m.distance
   match_point.append(k1[m.queryIdx].pt)
   pt1=list(k1[m.queryIdx].pt)
   pt1=[int(ii) for ii in pt1]
   pt2=list((k2[m.trainIdx].pt[0] + w1, k2[m.trainIdx].pt[1]))
   pt2=[int(ii) for ii in pt2]
   points1.append(pt1);#1
   points2.append(pt2);#1
   color = tuple([sp.random.randint(0, 255) for _ in xrange(3)])
   cv2.line(view, tuple(pt1), tuple(pt2), color)
points1=np.asarray(points1,dtype=float);
points2=np.asarray(points2,dtype=float);
liness=[]
F1,mask=cv2.findFundamentalMat(points1,
        points2,method=cv.CV_FM_RANSAC,param1=1,param2=0.99);
print F1
#points1 = cv.fromarray(points1)
#cv.ComputeCorrespondEpilines(points1,2, F1,liness)
#cv.ComputeCorrespondEpilines(cv.fromarray(points1),
         1,cv.fromarray(F1),cv.fromarray(liness))
mp_array=np.asarray(match_point,dtype=np.int)
print type(match_point)
print type(match_point[0])
print type(mp_array)
print mp_array
cv.ComputeCorrespondEpilines(match_point,1, cv.fromarray(F1),cv.fromarray(liness))
```

Comment: It is cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines, compute with small c